# Print a label using Windows form and Report?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, report

So basically I'm starting from scratch (with Windows Form) and I want to build a small program that simply prints out labels with some information written in the Form.

The reason for creating this question is not asking for codes, but I want to hear from you guys what is and what is not possible and what I should use and not etc. In other words, just discussing.

The Form will look something like this

```html
-----------------------------------------<br>
| Name: |TextfieldInput|                |<br>
| Company: |TextfieldInput|             |<br>
| Num of copies |TextfieldInput|        |<br>
| etc...                                |<br>
-----------------------------------------
```

and the result should look exactly like it, but with the input values of course. A simple application that prints out (numbers of) labels with the input information.

My experience with Windows Form is little, but I think I could manage some fields. My question: is "Reports" (among the projects in Visual Studio) something I can use to design the label and then print it out in Windows Forms? That is to say, can I pass my values from the Form to the Report before printing out the Report? If I could save some time not coding all the layout, then I think that is the way to go? Any suggestions?

All feedback are welcomed!

Comment: Is printing a requirement or can you export the data to pdf or word instead ? (or maybe excel)

Comment: Yes, as I want to print the labels as soon I'm done giving the inputs (efficiency). But on the other hand, if exporting the data and then printing them would not be an issue either. What were you thinking about?

Comment: I've come across this problem before, I had some data in a data grid and I wanted to print it to generate reports (salary payment), and the way I handled it was by exporting the data to Excel sheets. And you can exploit its Print function too.

Comment: I see. In my case, I think it would be too much "extra work" (delay) to do it that way. I'm looking at Crystal Report right now, hopefully someone can come with ideas. Thanks for your input!

Comment: It's easy to convert the data to Excel sheets. Those sheets are simply text files in which values have been separated by a tab character. Example `Name    Input`. Saving the file with `.xls` extensions results in the file being readable by excel and data being shown in columns. Excel prompts you that the file has not been created by the software. However, it's ok. Other choice is to use Office Interrps and that approach is a little lengthy.

Comment: Darn, I just can't believe it's so hard to find something this simple. Maybe I'm leaving something important out. I really need some guidance before I go mad haha =)

Still looking on Crystal Report..

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this, is have a textBox for every label and a button on the bottom. You can write whatever you want the labels to display in the textBoxes, then when you press the button, change the label.Text to whatever is written in the corresponding textBox.Text.